# Formulário HTML inputs

Tags: html, css, html-select

tenho um trabalho de faculdade de HTML e não consigo fazer conforme a imagem abaixo:
alinhamento e as máscaras de data de nascimento e CEP...

segue meu código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Atividade06</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="area">
    <form id="formulario" autocomplete="off">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Dados Pessoais</legend>
        <label>Nome:</label><input class="campo_nome" type="text">
        <label>Sobrenome:</label><input class="campo_email" type="password"><br><br>
        <label>Nascimento:</label><input type="date">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: COMO TEM QUE FICAR O FORMULÁRIO]

Comment: Edite a pergunta adicionando o *CSS*.

Comment: Na imagem não me parece mascara, a pessoa que fez o formulário da imagem, ao invés de usar um `input[type='date']`, como vc fez, ela usou 3 `input[type='text']`  ( 1 p/Dia, 1 p/Mes e 1 p/Ano )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já ouviu falar de CSS? Isso será necessário para estilizar (alinhar, determinar o tamanho dos inputs, etc) a sua página.

Pela imagem parece que a data de nascimento na verdade são 3 `<input>` com atributo placeholder para aparecer dd mm yyyy. Você pode usar `type="number"` para com atributos de max/min para que o usuário só possa colocar valores válidos.

Recomendo que em próximas perguntas você também coloque as soluções que tentou.